# Let $D$ be an ordered integral domain, and let $a\in D$. Prove that $a^2-a+1>0$

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $D$ be an ordered integral domain, and let $a\in D$. Prove that $a^2-a+1>0$.

This is quite simple if we were to take $\Bbb{R}$ as the ordered integral domain in question. However, as we cannot do that, how should we deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass to the quotient field and note $a^2 - a + 1 = (a-1/2)^2 + 3/4$, which must be positive. (Note that the charactersic of the domain is $0$, as it is ordered, whence $2$ and $4$ are non-zero and thus invertible in the quotient field.)

If you do not want to do this you could say: $a^2 - a+ 1 > 0$ if and only if 
$4(a^2 - a+ 1) > 0$. Then do the same as above, yet staying in the domain.

Comment: Why would you assume that $3/4$ is positive in an ordered integral domain? I know $3=1+1+1$ is. But why $3.4^{-1}$?

Comment: The multiplicative inverse of each positive element $a$ is positive. Assume not. Then $-a^{-1}$ is positive. So $a(-a^{-1})$ is positive. This is however $-1$, which is not positve, as $1$ is positive. So $4^{-1}$  is positve, whence also the product with $3$.